# How to set CrystalReports DataSource in Java?

Tags: java, vb.net, crystal-reports

I'm using the CrystalReports Java API I found here http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-29757

I want to use some existing reports in Java which were already used in a VB.NET application.

In VB.NET it was possible to select the data programmatically and set it as data source for the report:

```
Dim dpa As New OracleDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM table", conDatabase)
Dim dt As New DataTable
dpa.Fill(dt)

rpt.SetDataSource(dt)
```

How can I do this in Java?

Comment: It looks easy but it took me some time to figure it out. I figured it out after I wrote the question but before I posted it so I decided to answer it myself instead of canceling the post. Maybe someone will struggle with the same problem in the future and will find this helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's just as easy in Java:

```
ReportClientDocument reportClientDoc = new ReportClientDocument();
reportClientDoc.open(reportPath, 0);

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM table");

reportClientDoc.getDatabaseController().setDataSource(rs);
```